# What does (*new) do?

Tags: c, new-operator

I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue my application is having with the activemq-cpp-3.4.0 library, and gotten to the point that I'm tracing line by line to see where it's going wrong. The application problem itself is tangential to this question; I came across some code that I don't understand, and I'm hoping someone can explain what's going on.

Tracing down, I find the following code (note: this is technically within the apr library):

```
alloc_socket(new, cont);

/* For right now, we are not using socket groups.  We may later.
 * No flags to use when creating a socket, so use 0 for that parameter as well.
 */
(*new)->socketdes = socket(family, type, protocol);

if ((*new)->socketdes == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    return apr_get_netos_error();
}
```

I'm confused enough by the `alloc_socket(new, cont)`, but specifically I am interested in what's going on with the (*new) calls. Does this allocate another instance of `this`? If so, is it a fallacy to check the stored `socketdes` value by using `(*new)` again, as that would create another, separate, instance? Or am I just completely off track?

Comment: Are you sure this is C++? This looks like illegal C++ but legal C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is C code.  In C, `new` is an identifier, not a keyword.

Comment: Ah, well that explains quite a bit. So `new` in this context is just some inconveniently named variable?

Comment: Seems pretty convenient to me.

Comment: Fair enough...inconvenient for *me*, then.